# Stop SWRevealViewController animation when select

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

i am trying to disable SWRevealViewController animation when selecting the row, this is a sliding-menu library to use with swift or objective-c, what i am saying is when i select the row from the menu it expands like 40 px to the right then it close and goes away, i want to edit it so when i click on the row it close without expanding to the right.

I hope i explained well and this is the library i'm working with: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Answer (score 4):

Comment line number 1378 in SVRevealViewController.m:

```
_enqueue( [theSelf _setFrontViewPosition:preReplacementPosition withDuration:firstDuration] );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it saved us .